# Selenium webdriver does not click on element

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium

I have an issue with selenium webdriver is not able to click on one particular element
I am using ruby and this happens on chrome. everything works fine on firefox. Even on Chrome if I execute the script in debug mode, it is able to click that particular element. I tried with setting the focus on the element before click event and also with increased wait before click.
Nothing worked.

Thanks

Comment: Is an exception being thrown? Which exception? Can you share your relevant Selenese, and the relevant HTML?

Comment: Please provide more information.